# Querying into arrays with JSON_VALUE

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a field with the following JSON data in it

```
[
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DefinitionId":"82c4c49c-b6b2-4b02-8e2f-fbcba9f92fe4",
      "EngagementValue":60,
      "Id":"335c92ce-5e36-4b13-9472-4940ad66e75f",
      "Timestamp":"2019-05-07T23:53:34.4268677Z"
   }
]
```

I am trying to find all SQL rows that have the field `@odata.type` equal to `#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal`. But it is inside of an array. I have tried the SQL below, but I can't return any SQL rows.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [client_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
  WHERE JSON_VALUE([Events], '$.[0]"odata.type"') = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path as `'$[0]."@odata.type"'` (missing dot operator `.` that indicates a member of your `$[0]` object).

```
SELECT *
FROM [usms_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Events], '$[0]."@odata.type"') = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DefinitionId":"82c4c49c-b6b2-4b02-8e2f-fbcba9f92fe4",
      "EngagementValue":60,
      "Id":"335c92ce-5e36-4b13-9472-4940ad66e75f",
      "Timestamp":"2019-05-07T23:53:34.4268677Z"
   }
]'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0]."@odata.type"') AS JsonValue
```

Output:

```
----------------------- 
JsonValue
----------------------- 
#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal
```